# Last Character in a param in angular 2 routing is getting truncated

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am adding a hash to reset password link when I email it to the user: http://someapplication.com/resetpassword/YwSAVAIPQ8wQzvtI1mXjsMUbSqgwdxPx3fW4t2m9HX4=

When user tries to access the link, I read the hash from the link as a angular 2 parameter using this.route.snapshot.params['token']. While reading, the last character in the hash "=" is getting truncated. Can anyone tell me why and how do I fix it?

Comment: Probably angular truncates the '=' sign because it thinks it is an equal operator for a GET paramater. like someapplication.com/users?id=3
So don't you make that hash a get parameter? LIke app.resetpassword?hash=yourhashhere

Answer (score 1):

the `=` equal sign has special meaning in URI context, so you need encode your URL when you send URL to user.

```
let token = 'YwSAVAIPQ8wQzvtI1mXjsMUbSqgwdxPx3fW4t2m9HX4=';
let tokenEncoded = encodeURIComponent(token); // "YwSAVAIPQ8wQzvtI1mXjsMUbSqgwdxPx3fW4t2m9HX4%3D"
-> url: http://someapplication.com/resetpassword/YwSAVAIPQ8wQzvtI1mXjsMUbSqgwdxPx3fW4t2m9HX4%3D
```

then the router could get the value you expect.

Comment: Even after encoding I am getting same issue.